# Stopping Background Task On Page Navigation Back

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project that supports iOS and Android devices, and I'm using the MVVM design pattern.

I have navigation root page that consists of a ListView, when item is selected on this ListView, I execute the following command to Navigate to item details view.

```
Page DetailsPage = new View.DetailsView(SelectedItemData);
await Navigation.PushAsync(DetailsPage);
```

Once this Details Page is opened, I start running a background task.

```
private void StartBackgroundTask(){
    TimerBackgroundTask = new Timer((o) => {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Update()); }, null, 0, 1000);
    } 
}
```

Which is based on this class

```
public class Timer : CancellationTokenSource
{
    public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
    public Timer(Action<object> callback, object state, int dueTime, int period)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(dueTime, Token).ContinueWith(async (t, s) => 
        {
            Tuple<Action<object>, object> tuple = (Tuple<Action<object>, object>)s;

            while (!IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => tuple.Item1(tuple.Item2));
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(period);
            }
        },
        Tuple.Create(callback, state), CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        IsDisposed = true;
        if (disposing)
        {
            Cancel();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Update function updates UI every 1 second.

Everything works fine and as it should, no issues here, however problems start to occur once I navigate back to root page, and back to details page - doing so twice causes the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. Parameter name: jobject
```

The problem stops occurring once the StartBackgroundTask gets disabled entirely from the code, so I believe that it is the one responsible for the error. Furthermore, I'm fairly convinced that this background task keeps on running somewhere in the thread even though I navigate back to the root page and I believe that if I could somehow dispose of the background task OnDissapearing event / navigation back button pressed, the error would no longer persist.

Unfortunately I have no idea how I how or even if its possible to somehow bind command to navigation back pressed event given my Views are bound to ViewModel.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect that a page is being dismissed by overriding OnDisappearing. In your DetailPage you could have something like this:

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        TimerBackgroundTask?.Dispose();
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```

Comment: That whas my thought too, however it never executed on my ViewModel even if I inherited from Page class. Will have to try it again though.

Comment: Your ViewModel would not get the callback. The call to this method is called by Xamarin.Forms. If you want to intercept the callback in your ViewModel then you would have to expose a Command that would relay the call back from the ContentPage. So in OnDisappearing in your content page you would have smth like this: ViewModel.OnDisapperaingCommand.Execute()